# From where to download an Ubuntu ISO file?

Tags: iso

I was looking at page: "Create a bootable USB"
On page 2 under Requirements I found the following text:
You will need: "An Ubuntu ISO file". See: [Get Ubunty] for download links.
Clicking this link [Get Ubunty] lead to page:Ubunt downloads.
However there I did not find nya download access to: "An Ubuntu ISO file".
I conclude that your links do not appear to be consistent!

Do you have any suggestion for progress?

I have no previous Ubuntu version installed and have removed all previous Desktop Operating Systems. I intend to install Ubuntu on an off-line desktop.

Comment: https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?country=&version=18.04.3&architecture=amd64

Comment: Please edit you question and tell us about your computer. It will make it possible to suggest which version and flavour of Ubuntu that should work well in your computer. Otherwise we can only point you to a standard web page, [releases.ubuntu.com](http://releases.ubuntu.com)

Comment: @John Ronald  should change link your so people can see what they are downloading.  Your link starts the download.

Comment: The downloads you see are the ISOs, just not label as such.

Answer (score 1):

You can download an ISO from...
https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop